# How to filter the options of select component in the cell editor of Dojo GridX by the value of another cell?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

How to filter the options of the select component (`FilteringSelect` or `ComboBox`) by the value of another cell in the same row?

I'm using **GridX** version 1.2 with Dojo 1.9. I have rows with 2 select widgets, where one of them should be filtered by the second. This is similar to this example: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#codependent-filteringselect-combobox-widgets, only it happens in the same row.

I use the `gridx/modules/Edit` module for defining cell editor widgets. I know `decorator` and `onCellValue` functions, but the proble is, they are operating on the cell level. I was searching for the place to register callback, that would have access to the whole row after it was rendered, so I could register the listener, which would change one control after the other was modified, but I could't find anything.

Is it possible to achieve that effect with GridX without [big] modification to GridX source code? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

please refer the below URL
http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/gridx-combobox-with-label-value-pairs-td3994788.html
Thanks
kssrao

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, because if the link changes the answer is lost.  Its better to post the essentials.